# Proving Surjectivity when $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, f(a,b) = 2a-b$

Tags: functions

Suppose we have a function defined as $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, f(a,b) = 2a-b$

This was my solution:
Suppose $z\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then for some $x,y\in\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, f(x,y) = z.$

$2x-y = z$ 
$\Rightarrow -y=z-2x$ 
$\Rightarrow y = -z + 2x$

$2x = z + y$ 
$\Rightarrow{x = \frac{z+y}{2}}$

This was supposed to show values for $x$ and $y$ exist in the domain for all outputs. But I was told the following:

- Choice of $(a,b)$ may not be in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$
- Correct set up but did not choose $a$, $b$ appropriately, based on each case for $y(y>0, y<0, y=0)$

Could someone help me understand what this means?

Comment: Note that the [tag:proof-writing] tag has a different purpose. Also, please be aware that MathJax works in the title section.

Comment: What is the codomain of your function $f$? This is important when checking if a function is surjective. Based on you supposing $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, presumably your function is $f \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$? This sort of thing is important to state when you are first starting to write proofs.

Comment: I would add a further criticism of this solution: If I tell you $z=1$ for instance, your solution does not tell me what $x$ and $y$ should be.  The "solution" $y=-z+2x$ does not determine $y$ until you determine $x$ first.  Then $x=\frac{z+y}{2}$ does not determine $x$ until you first determine $y$.  So you really have not exhibited what $(x,y)\in\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ maps to $z$.

Comment: To add to what @Addem says: you have essentially just restated the question and not proven anything at all. Edward's solution is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Your function could be defined as $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ or as mapping to $\mathbb{Z}$, I am not sure which one is intended.

### Mapping to Natural Numbers

If you assume your codomain in $\mathbb{N}$, you must show that *every* natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ could be represented as an image of $f$. In other words, that there exist some $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a,b) = n$.

It remains to cleverly pick such $a,b$. You have
$$
n = f(a,b) = 2a-b.
$$
You can pick whatever $a,b$ you like (as long as they are natural numbers) to make the RHS equal the LHS. One simple choice is $a = n = b$, then you have
$$
f(a,b) = f(n,n) = 2n - n = n,
$$
as desired.

### Mapping to the Integers

If your codomain is $\mathbb{Z}$, you have to be able to represent all integers this way, not just all natural numbers. Could you come up with a way how to represent any integer with 2 natural numbers as the image of $f$?

Comment: f maps into the natural numbers? with domain N x N ?  i.e. $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove surjectivity, one needs to know what you are mapping onto. Assuming that one is mapping onto $\mathbb{Z}$, let us take $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then one can prove surjectivity by breaking into four cases:

1. $z < 0$: Let $x = 0$ and $y = z$. If you do not want to include 0 in $\mathbb{N}$, then we can take $x = 1$ and $y = z + 2$.
2. $z=0$: Let $x = y = 0$ or $x = 1$ and $y =2$.
3. $z > 0$ and even: Let $x = z/2.$
4. $z > 0$ and odd: Let $y = 1$ and $x = (z + 1)/2.$